# unable to start vm on kvm

Tags: kvm, virsh

I'm not able to start a vm on kvm with the following error

```
[root@dev1 RHEL5-7]# virsh start demo-57-test
error: Failed to start domain demo-57-test
error: Unable to add port vnet0 to OVS bridge br0: Operation not permitted
```

I defined the vm using my xml file with the following command

virsh define

Comment: Are there several VM definitions with `vnet0`? I.e. does `ip link` show `vnet0`? Is there an interface `br0`? If there is one then maybe SELinux, AppArmor or something like that prevents this modification.

Comment: Interface `br0` is defined and i can see that listed in `ifconfig` command.

Comment: But what about `vnet0`? BTW: You should get used to using `ip` instead of `ifconfig`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Identified the issue. The xml I used to define my domain/vm has `<virtualport type='openvswitch'>` and since I don't have `ovs` running on this box it gave that error. After I removed that line from my xml, vm comes up fine.
Thanks for the `ip` suggestion though(old habits die hard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml I used to define my domain/vm has  and since I don't have ovs running on this box it gave that error. After I removed that line from my xml, vm comes up fine.